# Making sense of an architecture for a FreeRTOS based application

Tags: embedded, c++, freertos

This is more of an architectural design question and any suggestions shall be appreciated.

So far, a general idea is that there's a system thread that's like a central task that decides how to delegate tasks based on what's being sent to the queue from a different thread.

In my case below, I have `uart_data.cpp` that has a function along with a callback which is called from the UART ISR once the UART data is done being sent.

**Concern:**
Is it better to have a class inside `uart_data.cpp` rather than free functions? Currently, the issue is `uart_data.cpp` doesn't have a reference for `systemTaskQueue` so I can't call `xQueueSendFromISR()`. With class, I could instantiate it and pass the queue to the constructor but I'm not sure if it makes sense to have a dedicated Class for mere parsing. Maybe I'm overthinking.

```
// main.cpp
Uart uart;

int main(void) {

  SystemTsk systemTsk(&uart);
  vTaskStartScheduler();    
}

// systemTsk.cpp
SystemTsk::SystemTsk(Uart &uart) : uart(uart)
{
    systemTaskQueue = xQueueCreate(queueSize, itemSize);
    if (systemTaskQueue == NULL)
    {
        // error handling
    }

    // create a task
    if (xTaskCreate(SystemTsk::run, "main", 256, this, 0, &taskHandle) != pdPASS)
    {
        // error handling
    }   
}

void SystemTsk::run(void *instance)
{
    auto pInstance = static_cast<SystemTsk*>(instance);
    pInstance->mainThread();
}

void SystemTsk::mainThread()
{   
  int data;
  while(true) 
  { 

     if (xQueueReceive(systemTaskQueue, &data, 0) == pdPASS) {
      // delegate stuff according to data
     }
    
  }
}

// uart_data.cpp
void parse(uint8_t buffer[])
{
  // parse the uart data
  // send the data to the queue to unblock the task via 
  xQueueSendFromISR
}

void uartCb(uint8_t buffer[])
{ 
   // ...
   parse(buffer);
}
```

Comment: You could always use a global variable.

Comment: is this a suggested approach though? also`systemTaskQueue` is a part of `SystemTsk` class

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it until the exigencies of your program logic requires it. So far you've described only a very simple situation where you have just one task and one uart object. Don't make your code more complicated than it needs to be. You'll never design the perfect system of objects. The point is knowing how to change things when the need arises.

Comment: But how would you try to access `alsosystemTaskQueue` if it's a part of the class and not a global?

Comment: Right now the SystemTsk creates the queue. You could instead make it a constructor parameter. Then the creator of the SystemTsk would be responsible for creating the queue and could pass it to both the SystemTsk and the Uart constructors.

Comment: I see, so perhaps have the queue defined in `main`, pass it to SystemTsk and Uart constructor, and then pass the queue to the `uartCb` as an argument from the ISR, yes? Meaning no real need to have a separate class inside `uart_data.cpp`?

Comment: Yes that's basically it.

Comment: right. Does defining the queue as static in main make sense to you?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's required/will make a difference in FreeRTOS.

Comment: This isn't possible to answer unless you explain why you are using RTOS and not bare metal. The choice of RTOS typically mean that you expect lots of complexity and lots of parallel execution of unrelated tasks. If the project just contains some UART comm and a few other peripherals, then RTOS is very likely just bloat and overkill.

Comment: As for general design, your main scheduler should call some "serial" module which knows about protocol decoding etc and which calls the driver in turn. It doesn't make sense to have some top-tier scheduler pass around that info, since none but the "serial" module is interested in the raw UART data anyway. That is, unless the UART data is so simplistic that you don't even have a protocol.

Comment: 1) I do plan on adding additional executions on top of it including BLE over UART, so then perhaps I could send and receive data over two different protocols. My main goal would be to run multiple things "simultaneously" while protecting the data via mutexes and other primitives. 2) So you're implying you don't see a point in passing a uart reference to `SystemTsk` and there should be an extra layer for the SystemTsk to interface to the UART driver with? Not quite sure why would that really need to be the case?